# liveware laravel popup occurs on keypress event on search bar and stops responding to cancel

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I am new to  laravel table view, I have implemented the same in laravel 10, but the problem is that when ever I try to search I get a pop up with "cancel" and "yes, I am Sure" button's the cancel button did not works and the other button throws a laravel error modal with "Unable to find the action" Exception.

Can any one help me with the solution, or I am doing any wrong step,

I have installed it from the official website https://laravelviews.com/table-view

This is my records table view

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Records;
use LaravelViews\Facades\Header;
use LaravelViews\Facades\UI;
use LaravelViews\Views\TableView;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;


class RecordsTableView extends TableView
{
    /**
     * Sets a model class to get the initial data
     */
    protected $model = Records::class;
    protected $paginate = 10;



    /**
     * Sets the headers of the table as you want to be displayed
     *
     * @return array<string> Array of headers
     */
    public function headers(): array
    {
        return [
            'Date',
            Header::title('Challan No')->sortBy('ChallanNo'),
            'Customer Name',
            'Address',
            'Mobile',
            'Serial Number',
            'Other Accessory',
            'Customer Problem',
            'Actual Problem',
            'Part Required',
            'Estimate',
            'Action Taken',
            'Advance Amount',
            'Page Count',
            'Amount',
            'Status',
            'Engineer Name',
            'Delivery',
            'Billing Done',
            'Any age',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Sets the data to every cell of a single row
     *
     * @param $model Current model for each row
     */
    public function row($model): array
    {
        return [
            $model->Date,
            $model->ChallanNo,
            $model->CustomerName,
            $model->Address,
            $model->Mobile,
            $model->SerialNumber,
            $model->OtherAccessory,
            $model->CustomerProblem,
            $model->ActualProblem,
            $model->PartRequired,
            $model->Estimate,
            $model->ActionTaken,
            $model->AdvanceAmount,
            $model->PageCount,
            $model->Amount,
            $model->Status,
            $model->EngineerName,
            $model->Delivery,
            $model->BillingDone,                                
            $model->AnyImage,
        ];
    }
    protected function repository()
    {
        return Records::query();
    }
    public $searchBy = ['ChallanNo', 'CustomerName'];

}
```